# Unable to join live video session react-native-webview android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-webview

I'm working on a live video session app. I have used the BigBlueButton API to develop the web version, which is working properly on the web. I'm trying to use that web app URL in my react native app using react-native-webview. In ios app, I'm able to join the session but I'm not able to join the session in android and while joining getting the following message

```
It looks like you're using an older version of a supported browser. Please upgrade your browser for full support.
```

**My dependency versions:**

react: 16.9.0

react-native: 0.61.5

react-native-webview: 8.2.1

[image: Message while joining an online session in react native android app]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: share you webview code here

Comment: https://github.com/saikatkundu/demoApp/blob/master/WebPage.js

Comment: are you using webrtc for video calling?

Comment: The web app is integrated with BigBlueButton.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add `userAgent` prop in webview

```
<WebView
    userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36"

  ...otherProps
/>
```

and also add `MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS` permission into `androidManifest.xml`

Comment: Though I have the granted permission from the user I'm not getting access to the microphone in webview.

Comment: @SaikatKundu can you try this mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={false}

Comment: After adding the permission for MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS everything working fine in android. Thank you @MuhammadNuman

Comment: @SaikatKundu can you add BIgBlueButton and error message in question so others can get help from your question

Comment: Surely I will add